# Is there a best way to organize Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

I've been doing a small web application, adding behaviors and appending DOM objects in Javascript using jQuery. The problem is that the code is starting to grow really fast and I don't know where to store it (either in the same page it's being used, or in a big js file).
At this point, I have:

- 1 js file with an object storing some
  synchronized information from a
  server, and with the most important
  methods (which should be used across
  the application). One of these
  methods include a DOM element
  generator (which then I add from
  within the desired web page).
- 1 js
  file with a big method which is
  called when window.ready that adds
  behaviors to a bunch of DOM object (only related to a webpage).
- Some  tags filled
  with code in the pages that didn't
  use the second js file. This code is also webpage related.

Now, you may be killing me with your eyes, and I know. This is definitely not a good (or at least not consistent) way to store Javascript. So, my question is:

**Is there a best way to organize Javascript code?**

I suppose that at least I should follow a rule, though the problem is that I'm not sure if it's best to have a js file for all the "global data and methods" and then store the other ones in smallers js files or , or simply give up and go for a tea.

What do you guys think? Thanks in advance!

*PS: Obviously code reutilization is a good point. However, the scripts I will be reusing the most are saved in the first js file (the one with global stuff).*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually store global scripts in a single common file, and each page has its separate script file.

You can store page specific script files along with the page (in the same folder) or replicate the directory structure of the site inside a common "scripts" folder (useful if you have many many script files), both ways I have the script files named as their page counterpart, to make mappings easy.

Also, you can use namespaces to further organize your code.

Comment: storing global scripts in a single common file is good practice (until it gets huge). +1

Comment: @Timothy Groote: The issue it's not really the file size, but how often the content of the file is used. If you have a 500 KiB script with 200 function, and each one is used in each page, there's no reason to split it, however if each page calls one or two of them you can create a "common" subfolder and place each function in a separate file.

Answer (score 5):

There's no hard and fast answer to this one, but one thing to bear in mind is that if you put as much javascript as possible in external files, it can be cached which will make subsequent visits to the page faster.

The rules I tend to follow are:

- All code that can be used in more than one place goes in external files
- No external files contain code that actually does anything, the files serve as libraries of code I can use.
- The page itself contains minimal javascript code to initialize the code in my libraries.
- If this initialization code takes more than 10 or so lines of code then it's worth looking into putting it into a function/method in the library
- All javascript goes as near the bottom of the page as possible, just before the `</body>` tag.  This is because when the browser encounters a `<script>` tag it will stop rendering the page and evaluate the script before continuing. This can make the page feel slower to the user (though there's no actual difference in load time, perception matters!)
- Only scripts that absolutely must go in the head are put there for the reason described above.

EDIT: If you are including a lot of javascript files in a page then it is worth looking into consolodating them into a single file.  This is because every `<script src="...">` tag in a page will trigger a HTTP request, and the specs say that there can only ever be two requests open per domain at any one time.  Putting them all in a single file will also increase the benefit you will get from using a JS compressor such as closure or YUI, and the benefits from using mod_gzip

yslow is a good tool for determining optimizations to speed up page loading, it has plenty of advice to offer regarding javascript file optimizations. .

Answer (score 1):

If you use an object oriented design strategy, the answer to 'in which file does the code go' almost answers itself.

The beefy parts of the javascript (your class definitions and massive methods) should go into appropriate .js files, (a class definition usually gets its own .js file)
but the initialization code should go into the html page where they are utilized.

jQuery offers a good example :

it has its own .js file for the main class and function definitions,
and it allows you to add plugins which perform specific tasks, each in their own .js file.

Once you want to use jQuery, just add the jQuery script.
Want the plugin on this page too? add that one as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I understand your question right, so you can organize your code with modules, which will be connected in one file further.

For modules you can use CommonJS technique. It looks like this:

```
(function(window) {
  var Module = {};

  window.Module = Module;
})(window);
```

And addition:

```
(function(module) {
  module.NewProp = {};

})(window.Module);
```

Of course, you can use your own variables instead window etc.

And, if you will use Node.js - it's a good way to share variables between server and client.

```
(function(exports) {
  exports.Func = function(){};

})(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? wow : exports);
```

Hope it helps!